# Count distinct values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data set asking a customer how many pets they have for example. Is there a way with one query I can count the distinct values (1,2,3, etc)?
Thanks!

```
+----------+------+
| Customer | Pets |
+----------+------+
|       20 |    2 |
|       21 |    3 |
|       22 |    3 |
|       23 |    2 |
|       24 |    4 |
+----------+------+
```

What I want is a list saying:

- 2 had 2 Pets
- 2 had 3 Pets
- 1 had 4 Pets

Answer (score 123):

You can do a distinct count as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT column_name) FROM table_name;
```

EDIT:

Following your clarification and update to the question, I see now that it's quite a different question than we'd originally thought. "DISTINCT" has special meaning in SQL. If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

- 2 customers had 1 pets
- 3 customers had 2 pets
- 1 customers had 3 pets

Now you're probably going to want to use a subquery:

```
select COUNT(*) column_name FROM (SELECT DISTINCT column_name);
```

Let me know if this isn't quite what you're looking for.

Comment: I had tried that previous with zero luck. Here is an example of my data;
Customer | Pets
20 | 2
21 | 3
22 | 3
23 | 2
24 | 4

What I want is a list saying:
2 had 2 Pets
2 had 3 Pets
1 had 4 Pets

Comment: I actually was looking for the original version, and the first part of this solution worked for me. Thanks for not deleting it!

Comment: The edited query doesn't work for me as it doesn't contain the table name? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 52):

Ok, I deleted my previous answer because finally it was not what willlangford was looking for, but I made my point that maybe we were all misunderstanding the question.

I also thought of the `SELECT DISTINCT...` thing at first, but it seemed too weird to me that someone needed to know how many people had a different number of pets than the rest... thats why I thought that maybe the question was not clear enough.

So, now that the real question meaning is clarified, making a subquery for this its quite an overhead, I would preferably use a `GROUP BY` clause.

Imagine you have the table `customer_pets` like this:

```
+-----------------------+
|  customer  |   pets   |
+------------+----------+
| customer1  |    2     |
| customer2  |    3     |
| customer3  |    2     |
| customer4  |    2     |
| customer5  |    3     |
| customer6  |    4     |
+------------+----------+
```

then

```
SELECT count(customer) AS num_customers, pets FROM customer_pets GROUP BY pets
```

would return:

```
+----------------------------+
|  num_customers  |   pets   |
+-----------------+----------+
|        3        |    2     |
|        2        |    3     |
|        1        |    4     |
+-----------------+----------+
```

as you need.

Comment: The column name in `count(customer)` is superfluous. You can just use: `SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_customers, pets FROM customer_pets GROUP BY pets`

Comment: @sgussman Not excactly, if you allow NULL values for `customer` then `COUNT(customer)` will not count them, while `COUNT(*)` or `COUNT(pets)` will. In that case it depends on what behaviour you prefer. In any case even if it does not make a difference most of the time I like to specify the column I want to count for readability.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this link](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-count-with-distinct.php) is pretty good.

Sample output from that link:

```
mysql> SELECT cate_id,COUNT(DISTINCT(pub_lang)), ROUND(AVG(no_page),2)
    -> FROM book_mast
    -> GROUP BY cate_id;
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
| cate_id | COUNT(DISTINCT(pub_lang)) | ROUND(AVG(no_page),2) |
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
| CA001   |                         2 |                264.33 | 
| CA002   |                         1 |                433.33 | 
| CA003   |                         2 |                256.67 | 
| CA004   |                         3 |                246.67 | 
| CA005   |                         3 |                245.75 | 
+---------+---------------------------+-----------------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
select count(customer) as count, pets
from table
group by pets
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CUSTOMER, COUNT(*) as PETS 
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY CUSTOMER;
```