# Eloquent ORM resulting MySQL select not returning all rows

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm, laravel-4, eloquent

I am using Laravel's Eloquent ORM to query a database for infomation, but for some reason the resulting query isn't returning all of the rows.

**Eloquent Query:**

```
\Permit::selectRaw('CONCAT(lk_departments.dept_id, ".") AS dept_id, '. 
                   'lk_departments.dept_name, '.
                   'COUNT(DISTINCT permits.permit_number) AS total')
       ->leftJoin('lk_departments', 'permits.dept_id', '=', 'lk_departments.dept_id')
       ->where('permits.permit_number', '!=', 'N/A')
       ->whereBetween('permits.valid_date', [$query_info['start_date'], $query_info['end_date']])
       ->groupBy('lk_departments.dept_name')
       ->orderBy('lk_departments.dept_name', 'ASC')
       ->get()
```

**Resulting Query:**

```
SELECT 
CONCAT(lk_departments.dept_id, ".") AS dept_id, lk_departments.dept_name,
COUNT(DISTINCT permits.permit_number) AS total
FROM permits
LEFT JOIN lk_departments ON permits.dept_id = lk_departments.dept_id
WHERE permits.valid_date BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '12/12/2100'
GROUP BY lk_departments.dept_name
ORDER BY lk_departments.dept_name ASC
```

**Returned Data:**

```
dept_id             dept_name                       total
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL   NULL                                       0    | 
| 1.     Academic Achievement-(Special Services)    11   | 
| 3.     Academic Clubs                             1    | 
| 4.     Academic Custodial & Grounds Services      1    | 
| 5.     Accounting                                 2    | 
| 6.     Admissions                                 356  | 
| 7.     Advanced Programs Dept (Education Dept)    8    | 
| 9.     Aerospace Studies - Air Force ROTC         1    | 
| 11.    American Federation of Teachers            0    | 
| 13.    Anthropology                               1    | 
| 14.    Art Dept.                                  4    | 
| 17.    Athletic Dept.                             11   | 
| 21.    Biology Dept.                              2    | 
|                                                        |
| ...    ...                                        ...  |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

I referenced this question to modify `total`: [Count distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688814/count-distinct-values)

but I still receive one `NULL` row with a `total` of `0` and missing records. I'm not very good with MySQL, so forgive me if I am missing something. Ideally, I would like a count of permits from each department for a given time frame.

**NOTE:**
`dept_id` = auto incremented primary key
`permits` = table containing parking permit information that is linked to a department

Comment: Would adding a where `dept_id IS NOT NULL` not omit that unwanted row?

Comment: For some reason, adding `dept_id IS NOT NULL` returns an empty set.

Comment: That's especially odd. As a note you should avoid doing presentation-type things in your query, such as appending `.` to the number, instead save that for when it's shown in whatever view it's ending up in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem. When I was using `permits` as the master table in the join, I neglected to realize that the records for `dept_id` wouldn't show up if there were no corresponding records from `permits.dept_id` that matched `lk_departments.dept_id` (if nobody had registered a permit for that department, in other words). Also, for some reason, I had to change the query to include records where `permits.permit_number is null`.

**Resulting Eloquent Query:**

```
LKDepartment::selectRaw('lk_departments.*, COUNT(permits.permit_number) AS total')
            ->leftJoin('permits', 'lk_departments.dept_id', '=', 'permits.dept_id')
            ->whereNull('permits.permit_number')
            ->orWhereRaw("(permits.permit_number != 'N/A' AND permits.valid_date BETWEEN '$query_info[start_date]' AND '$query_info[end_date]')")
            ->groupBy('lk_departments.dept_id')
            ->orderBy('lk_departments.dept_id', 'ASC')
            ->get()
```

**Resulting Query:**

```
SELECT lk_departments.* , COUNT( permits.permit_number ) AS total
FROM lk_departments
LEFT JOIN permits ON lk_departments.dept_id = permits.dept_id
WHERE permits.permit_number IS NULL
OR (
    permits.permit_number != 'N/A' 
    AND permits.valid_date BETWEEN '01/01/2000' AND '12/12/2100'
)
GROUP BY lk_departments.dept_id
ORDER BY lk_departments.dept_id ASC
```

**Returned Data:**

```
dept_id             dept_name                       total
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| NULL   NULL                                       0    | 
| 1      Academic Achievement-(Special Services)    11   | 
| 2      Academic Advising Center                   0    | 
| 3      Academic Clubs                             1    | 
| 4      Academic Custodial & Grounds Services      1    | 
| 5      Accounting                                 2    | 
| 6      Admissions                                 356  | 
| 7      Advanced Programs Dept (Education Dept)    8    | 
| 8      Advisory Council                           0    | 
| 9      Aerospace Studies - Air Force ROTC         1    | 
| 10     Alternative School                         0    | 
| 11     American Federation of Teachers            0    | 
| 12     Anthropology                               0    | 
|                                                        |
| ...    ...                                        ...  |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess using an orm you cant do a case. You should solve the problem programatically, its better practice if you are using an orm, the idea is to map the database into objects without treat the results

Comment: You can use case with Eloquent ORM using the `selectRaw` method. This is just the resulting query **after** using Eloquent.