# How I use mysql count with select query?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a mysql select query like this:

```
select r.restaurant_id, r.restaurant_name, r.city_id, c.name
from restaurants r
inner join cities c on c.id = r.city_id;
```

This is the result of above query:

```
+---------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+
| restaurant_id | restaurant_name      | city_id | name        |
+---------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+
|             7 | Somasiri Bake House  |       5 | Mumbai      |
|             8 | Indian    Bake House |       7 | Chennai     |
|             9 | KFC Rest             |       5 | Mumbai      |    
|            10 | Indian t             |       5 | Mumbai      |
+---------------+----------------------+---------+-------------+
```

Now I want to display all the available cities with the number of restaurants existing to one city.

Eg: **Mumbai (3), Chennai(1)** and so on

I tried it like below with mysql `COUN()`, but it doesn't work for me.

```
SELECT c.name, count(r.city_id) AS count
FROM cities c
INNER JOIN restaurants r ON c.id = r.city_id;
```

Can anybody tell me what is the wrong with this?

Hope somebody may help me out. 
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4728175/2625561

Comment: You are missing a `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c.name, COALESCE(count(r.city_id), 0) AS count
FROM cities c
LEFT JOIN restaurants r ON c.id = r.city_id
GROUP BY c.id
```

Comment: Can not get all available cities.

Comment: Yes.. This is what I needed. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

That's called a grouping or aggregate query, you need to tell it how to group your elements.

Just add

```
GROUP BY r.restaurant_id, r.restaurant_name, r.city_id, c.name
```

at the end, before your final semi-colon.

Comment: I'd encourage the correct use of `GROUP BY` (not MySQL's incorrect behavior) by adding _all_ the `SELECT` columns to the group:  `GROUP BY r.restaurant_id, r.restaurant_name, r.city_id, c.name`  Using `GROUP BY r.city_id` alone would be an error in almost any other database.

Comment: yes its working... but it doesnt select all the cities

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski . . . I agree with you in general.  However, this particular example is not incorrect behavior according to ANSI, because of the notion of functional dependence.  I think Postgres, which may be the only database that implements this functionality correctly, does an adequate job of explaining the notion (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-select.html).

Comment: Can we select all available cities even if there is no any restaurant

Comment: I agree with @MichaelBerkowski, grouping by all un-aggregated columns is ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple group by if you don't want restaurant data:

```
select c.name, count(r.city_id) as available
from cities c
left join restaurants r on c.id = r.city_id
group by r.city_id
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca39e/5).

---

Or, if you want restaurant data too, select from cities first, then left join to other tables so cities without restaurants still get returned. Add a left join to a subquery that calculates each city's frequency:

```
select
  r.restaurant_id,
  r.restaurant_name,
  c.id,
  c.name,
  coalesce(available, 0) available
from cities c
left join restaurants r on c.id = r.city_id
left join (select city_id, count(*) available from restaurants group by 1) a
  on a.city_id = r.city_id
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca39e/2).

Comment: Bohemian, your query returned all the available restaurants with city counts. But I need to display all the cities and if there are restaurant for  these cities then  I need to display count number along with city.

Comment: @user3733831 do you want a zero in the "available" column for each city that has no restaurants in it, and to display nulls for the restaurant details in that case?

Comment: Yes it may have null values for cities. Reason is there are no restaurants for every cities and I don't need to have duplicate of cities in the query. Thank you.

Comment: @user3733831 try the new version (sqlfiddle link has been updated too)

Comment: Yes dear.. your query is working. But city names are duplicating. Actually I need like `city1 (3), city2 (5), city3 (8), city4 (11), city5`