# Select count of rows from the same table

Tags: mysql

Hi I have a table as below and I need to select the count of different trade IDs for given distinct OrderIds I am unable to do so in MySQL format

```
+-----------+---------+
| OrderID   |TradeID  |
+===========+=========+
| 1         | 58761   |
+-----------+---------+
| 1         | 58762   | 
+-----------+---------+
| 2         | 58763   | 
+-----------+---------+
| 2         | 58764   | 
+-----------+---------+
| 2         | 58765   |
+-----------+---------+
```

Where result is required as

```
+-----------+---------+
| OrderID   |Count    |
+===========+=========+
| 1         | 2       |
+-----------+---------+
| 2         | 4       | 
+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: Not sure about the mysql syntax, but it should be something like `select OrderID, count(*) from ``table`` group by OrderID`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count distinct values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688814/count-distinct-values)

Comment: Not working as this is giving result as

OrderID-1 , count -5

Answer (score 0):

Just COUNT / GROUP BY

```
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(*) 
FROM some_table 
GROUP BY OrderID
```

SQL Fiddle here:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/305630/1

Note that if you wanted a couple of distinct TradeIDs for each OrderID you could use

```
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(DISTINCT TradeID) 
FROM some_table 
GROUP BY OrderID
```