# mysql Count of names using same number

Tags: mysql, select

My Mysql table look like this

```
Field A         Field B
Red             yes
Blue                yes
Red             no
Green           no
Blue                yes
Blue                yes
Green           no
Green           yes
Red             no
```

I want the result to be:

```
Red     1
Blue        3
Green   1
```

Any help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count distinct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688814/count-distinct-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT FieldA, count(FieldA)
FROM table
WHERE table.FieldB = "yes"
GROUP BY FieldA
```

Answer (score 0):

conditional count

```
SELECT FieldA, COUNT( CASE WHEN FieldB = 'Yes' THEN 1 END)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY FieldA
```